# My DateTime field is being set in the past, when it shouldn't

Tags: apex, datetime

I have a field on my Case object called Need_By__c. This field works with an api that determines when to call customers. The business rules are as follows:

> If that Dialer_Status__c == 'Finalized' AND
>
> the Need_By__c value is in the past,
>
> switch the Dialer_Status__c = 'Ready' AND
>
> determine the new Need_By__c based on current DateTime
>
> once Dialer_Status__c == 'Ready', the api that makes the calls will try to call the customer around the time the Need_By__c is set to.

Code in the batch, which runs every 15 minutes.

```
List<Case> recordsToUpdate = new List<Case>();
Integer needByHoursToAdd = 6;

Set<String> phoneQueueStatusValues = new Set<String>();
DateTime now = DateTime.now(); //Did this here so all record updates get stamped the same. 

phoneQueueStatusValues.add('INITIAL CALL');
phoneQueueStatusValues.add('FOLLOW UP CALL');

for(Case c : [select 
                    Id,
                    Status,
                    Need_By__c,
                    Dialer_Status__c 
                from 
                    Case])
{           
    
    //If it meets the criteria, add back into the phone queue by flipping the Dialer_Status__c to "Ready"
    if(!String.isBlank(c.Dialer_Status__c) &&
        c.Dialer_Status__c.trim().equalsIgnoreCase('Finalized') &&
        phoneQueueStatusValues.contains(c.Status.trim().toUpperCase()) &&
        c.Need_By__c < now)
    {
        c.Dialer_Status__c = 'Ready';
    
        //Update need by datetime in case it falls in a range that is not allowed
        c.Need_By__c = Utility.getNeedByDateTime(now.addHours(needByHoursToAdd));
    
    }       
    
    recordsToUpdate.add(c);             
}


update recordsToUpdate;
```

The Utility class

```
public class Utility 
{
    public static DateTime getNeedByDateTime(DateTime dt)
    {
        if(dt == null)
        {
            return null;
        }

        //Add an hour to the datetime per business rules
        dt = dt.addHours(1); //This needs to add the hour even though the NewLeaf integration does not
        Integer minute = 0;
        Integer second = 0;
        
        
        if(dt.minute() > 0 &&
            dt.minute() < 30)
        {
            //Round to the half hour
            minute = 30;
        }
    
        
        DateTime newDt = DateTime.newInstance(dt.year(), dt.month(), dt.day(), dt.hour(), minute, second);  
        
        newDt = moveNeedByToNextDay(newDt);

        return newDt;
    }   
    
    private static DateTime moveNeedByToNextDay(DateTime needByDateTime)
    {
        Set<String> weekdays = new Set<String>();
        
        weekdays.add('MONDAY');
        weekdays.add('TUESDAY');
        weekdays.add('WEDNESDAY');
        weekdays.add('THURSDAY');
        weekdays.add('FRIDAY');
        
        String dayOfWeek = getDayOfWeek(needByDateTime, false).trim().toUpperCase();
        Integer daysToAdd = 0;
        Integer hour = needByDateTime.hour();
        
        if((hour <= 8 || 
            hour >= 18) &&
            weekdays.contains(dayOfWeek))
        {
            if(dayOfWeek.equalsIgnoreCase('FRIDAY'))
            {
                daysToAdd = 1;
                hour = 10; //10 AM start
            }
            else
            {
                daysToAdd = 0;
                hour = 8;               
            }
        }
        else if((hour <= 10 || 
                hour >= 16) &&
                dayOfWeek.equalsIgnoreCase('SATURDAY'))
        {
            daysToAdd = 2;
            hour = 8;           
        }
        else if(dayOfWeek.equalsIgnoreCase('SUNDAY'))
        {
            daysToAdd = 1;
            hour = 8;           
        }
        
        needByDateTime.addDays(daysToAdd);
        
        DateTime newNeedByDateTime = DateTime.newInstance(needByDateTime.year(),
                                                            needByDateTime.month(),
                                                            needByDateTime.addDays(daysToAdd).day(),
                                                            hour,
                                                            needByDateTime.minute(),
                                                            0);
        
        return newNeedByDateTime;
    }    

    public static String getDayOfWeek(DateTime dt, Boolean asShortDateValue)
    {
        String dtString = '';
        
        if(asShortDateValue)
        {
            dtString = dt.format('E');
        }
        else
        {
            dtString = dt.format('EEEE');
        }

        return dtString;
    }   
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the field tracking history of the Need By field showing the odd behavior of this batch. If you look closely, it's setting the Need By to the past, e.g. 06/04 3:30pm to 06/04 8am. Since this happens, the api that makes the calls is making extra calls to the customer, which in turn makes the batch update the Need By more often by changes the Cases status to Ready.

[image]

Comment: Commenting to follow up later as we'd suggested in chat that you post more about the root issue.

Comment: @CharlesT updated :D

Comment: I think if I change all my DateTime functions to GMT, I should be good

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DateTime.newInstanceGMT` presumes that the values you're putting in are in GMT time; in practice, this means that you actually constructed a new DateTime that is offset by your time zone offset.

You used `DateTime.format(dateTimeString)`, which always returns local time. If you wanted GMT values, you'd use `DateTime.formatGMT(dateTimeString)`, which would return the appropriate GMT values instead of your local time.

Comment: If format returns local, why isn't my second debug local?

Comment: @TylerZika Because System.debug's default behavior is to log everything in GMT.

Comment: Wtf... So If I need local in my code, I should use the second debug even though it doesnt return local?

Comment: @TylerZika Don't confuse the value in the DateTime with what System.debug prints. If you need the local time in your code, use the appropriate non-GMT methods (e.g. format instead of formatGMT). If you want to *debug* in your local time zone, consider `System.debug(myDT.format());` instead.

Comment: Trust me, until you get used to how things work, you're going to have a rough time of it. I once spent a week trying to get a datetime thing working right on one of my projects because of confusion like this. If you're having problems with your code, you should probably ask about the specific problem you're having; System.debug only complicates the issue of understanding.

Comment: So using datetime.now() for local date time in my code is a big no no?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79645/discussion-between-sfdcfox-and-tyler-zika).